# What does the "functional induction" tactic do in Coq?

Tags: coq, coq-tactic

I have used `functional induction` in this proof that I have been trying. As far as I understand, it essentially allows one to perform induction on *all* parameters of a recursive function "at the same time".

[The tactics page](https://coq.inria.fr/refman/proof-engine/tactics.html#coq:tacn.function-induction) states that:

> The tactic functional induction performs case analysis and induction following the definition of a function. It makes use of a principle generated by Function

I assume that **principle** is something technical whose definition I do not know. What does it mean?

In the future, how do I find out *what* this tactic is doing? (Is there some way to access the `LTac`?)

Is there a more canonical way of solving the theorem which I pose below?

```
Require Import FunInd.
Require Import Coq.Lists.List.
Require Import Coq.FSets.FMapInterface.
Require Import FMapFacts.
Require Import FunInd FMapInterface.


Require Import
        Coq.FSets.FMapList
        Coq.Structures.OrderedTypeEx.

Module Import MNat := FMapList.Make(Nat_as_OT).
Module Import MNatFacts := WFacts(MNat).



Module Import OTF_Nat := OrderedTypeFacts Nat_as_OT.
Module Import KOT_Nat := KeyOrderedType Nat_as_OT.
(* Consider using https://coq.inria.fr/library/Coq.FSets.FMapFacts.html *)
(* Consider using https://coq.inria.fr/library/Coq.FSets.FMapFacts.html *)
(* Consider using https://coq.inria.fr/library/Coq.FSets.FMapFacts.html *)

Definition NatToNat := MNat.t nat.
Definition NatToNatEmpty : NatToNat := MNat.empty nat.

(* We wish to show that map will have only positive values *)
Function insertNats (n: nat)  (mm: NatToNat)  {struct n}: NatToNat :=
  match n with
  | O => mm
  | S (next) => insertNats  next (MNat.add n n mm)
  end.

Theorem insertNatsDoesNotDeleteKeys:
  forall (n: nat) (k: nat) (mm: NatToNat),
    MNat.In k mm -> MNat.In k (insertNats n mm).
  intros n.
  intros k mm.
  intros kinmm.
  functional induction insertNats n mm.
  exact kinmm.
  rewrite add_in_iff in IHn0.
  assert(S next = k \/ MNat.In k mm).
  auto.
  apply IHn0.
  exact H.
Qed.
```

Comment: A few comments: Induction principles are just peculiar lemmas, which Coq autogenerates for each datatype. For instance, usual induction on numbers is lemma `nat_ind`. `Function` generates such lemmas; by `Function`’s docs, the lemma being used here should be called something like `insertNats_ind`, and `Check insertNats_ind` or `Print insertNats_ind` should show it.
On the Ltac, docs also say that `functional induction (f x1 x2 x3) is actually a wrapper for induction x1, x2, x3, (f x1 x2 x3) using qualid`; its definition should be in `FunInd`.

Comment: Your example code is missing some `Require` to make it work. There is no way to access "the Ltac" when a tactic is not programmed in Ltac, which is the case for most Coq tactics. However you may use `Show Proof` before and after using a tactic to see exactly what it did.

Comment: There's a dead link where you say "The tactics page says ..."

Comment: Thanks, I fixed the link!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The "principle" just means "an induction principle" - a complete set of cases that must be proved in order to prove some motive "inductively".

The difference between `Function` and `Fixpoint` in Coq is that the former creates an induction principle and recursion principle based on the given definition, and then each return value is passed in (as a lambda, if there are variables bound by case analysis or there is a recursive call's value involved). This generally computes slower. The principles generated are with respect to a generated Inductive type, each variant of which is a case of the function's call scheme. The latter `Fixpoint` uses Coq's limited termination analysis to justify the well-foundedness of a function's recursion*. `Fixpoint` is faster, because it uses OCaml's own pattern matching and direct recursion in computation.

How is the induction scheme created? First, all the function parameters are abstracted into a `forall`. Then, each branch of a match expression creates a new case to prove for the scheme (the number of cases multiplies for each nested match). All the "return" positions in a function are in scope of some number of match expressions' bindings; each binding is an argument to an induction case that must produce the motive on the reconstructed arguments (e.g., if in the case of a `list A`'s `cons`, we have an `a : A` and a `list_a : list A` binding, so then we must produce a `Motive (cons a list_a)` result). If there is a recursive call with the `list_a` argument, then we get a further binding of an induction hypothesis of type `Motive list_a`.

An actual Coq implementer will probably correct me on the specifics of the above, but it's more or less how induction schemes are inferred from well-founded recursive functions.

This is all fairly rough, and better explained in the documentation on [Function](https://coq.inria.fr/refman/gallina-ext.html#sec83) and [Functional Scheme](https://coq.inria.fr/refman/schemes.html#sec657).

- The termination analysis is maybe was too smart for its own good. It needed to be revised (by IIRC Maxime Dénès, good job) following a [proof of False](https://sympa.inria.fr/sympa/arc/coq-club/2013-12/msg00119.html) given (a consequence of) the univalence axiom.